# Adding column to a large table: datatype or INT or reference table?

Tags: mysql, database, reference, binary, set

I have a table with 300.000+ records.

I want to add some "markers" to a little portion of the records (0.5% or less);

what would be the best choice:

- Use an INT field and treat it like a binary string

  marker 0: xxxxx1 will be stored as 1,

  marker 0 and 3: xx1001 will be stored as 9, ecc..
- Use a SET datatype
- Use reference table and join them; something like

  mydata: id | ..

  markers: id | marker

  mydata_marker: mydata_id | markers_id
- Add other fields (I do not like the idea of ​​filling a table with zeros)

I find the first option "cute" and simple to implement, but perhaps problematic to change at a later time.

I do not know how to comment on the second option, because I never used that datatype.

At a guess I would go for the third option ...

any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Given you say only 0.5% of the records will have any markers at all, you'd be better off splitting the markers off into their own child table. Once you've got that child table, then you wouldn't be wasting nearly as much space and could use an int, a literal mysql [bit field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-literals.html), individual per-flag fields, etc...

e.g. Assuming only 8 flags, you'd need a tinyint field, which is 1 byte. That'd be ~290kbytes of storage wasted. Separating it out into its own child table, there's a wee bit of overhead for the new table, and then ~10k of storage for the individual flag records.

Answer (score 2):

I would outright avoid the first option because it requires outside processing or ugly queries to figure out what is going on and it will make changing how those markers work later a pain.

I would use the third option: make a table of markers with whatever information you are attaching to those (at least id and name) and a table for has_marker or something similar. has_marker just needs the primary key of your existing record and the primary key of the marker you are adding. Include foreign keys, a unique (record_id, marker_id) if that fits your data model, and consider indexing both columns as a speed boost, depending on what your code is doing with them.

This might be a little bulky, but it gives you the most freedom for implementation and future changes. It also keeps all your data in the database (instead of needing both database and your interpretation of what markers are meant by '9' or '1001010101' or any other similar system), and makes it easy to query from both directions (what markers does this record have OR what records have this/these markers) with simple joins. Finally, adding a totally new marker with this method is trivial - make a new row in the marker table and add to has_marker for each record that should have it.